# Import and export flows programmatically in Node-red

Tags: node.js, node-red

What are the available API to do this?
I wanna be able to export and import both flows and configuration flows.

Answer (score 3):

Node-RED does not have a published runtime api currently. This is something we're working on as part of the roadmap to a stable 1.0 release.

In the meantime, you can use the HTTP Admin API - https://nodered.org/docs/api/admin/methods/ - refer to the `/flow` endpoints.